# Why does soup.get_text() include comments in some situations?

Tags: beautifulsoup, ms-word, lxml

I have an HTML document that I've created by exporting a MS Word doc. In Word, I saved as the `Web Page (.HTM)` format, not the `Web Page, Filtered (.HTM)` format.

When I run get_text on the doc, it includes the comments in the style tag for some reason. This is unexpected. BS4 *does* ignore the 2nd comment in the body as expected.

I've tried with both the `lxml` and `html.parser` parsers. Same result.

Python 3.9.12, IPython 8.4.0, BS 4.8.2 (though when I use pkg_resources.get_distribution("bs4").version, it shows 0.0.1)

```
html = """<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Helvetica;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    text-align:justify;
    text-justify:inter-ideograph;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
 /* Page Definitions */
 @page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='word-wrap:break-word'>
<div class=WordSection1>
<div style='border-top:double windowtext 2.25pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:
double windowtext 2.25pt;border-right:none;padding:1.0pt 0in 1.0pt 0in'>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:.25in;border:none;padding:0in'><span
style='font-size:9.0pt'>&nbsp;</span></p>
<!-- Some other random comment that get_text ignores -->
</div>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
soup.get_text()
```

```
In [5]: soup.get_text()
Out[5]: '\n\n\n\n\n<!--\n /* Font Definitions */\n @font-face\n\t{font-family:Helvetica;\n\tpanose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}\n /* Style Definitions */\n p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\n\t{margin:0in;\n\ttext-align:justify;\n\ttext-justify:inter-ideograph;\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\n\tfont-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}\n /* Page Definitions */\n @page WordSection1\n\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\n\tmargin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;}\ndiv.WordSection1\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\n /* List Definitions */\n ol\n\t{margin-bottom:0in;}\n-->\n\n\n\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\n'
```

Comment: could not reproduce the issue, works as expected, but to clarify may also post some information concerning versions of modules. Thanks

Comment: Strange. Let me do that. What information would you want specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue [running your code just returns `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n` for me <sub>(bs4 4.11.1, python 3.7.15, IPython 7.9.0)</sub>], but I expect it's because everything inside the `style` tag is stored as one `Stylesheet` element rather than being further parsed into Tag/NavigableString/Comment/etc

[image: stylesheet vs comment]

I don't think that's a valid html anyway - stylesheet comments should be like `/*Some Comment*/`, and you can't just put html inside a stylesheet like that...

Comment: I'm going to close this since 2 people haven't been able to reproduce. Thanks for taking a look anyway!

Comment: @Peter thanks for accepting my answer, but your comment indicates that you were maybe hoping for something a bit more helpful. Since your question only asked *why*, I just offered a possible explanation, but if you want to have more control over the text you extract, you can use something like [this function](https://pastebin.com/fh4P45iE), which will let you skip all style tags if you call it like `html_to_text(soup, specialTags={'style': ['""']})`

Comment: (you could even modify the function to parse inside `style` tags like normal html, but please remember that **html is not recognized inside `style` tags** - they should only contain css)

Comment: Yeah, that added invalid HTML inside style tags bit seems to be an interesting feature of the Words Doc to HTML conversion